# How can I get filleUploaded URL as string from async task in android

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-async-http

I am uploading an image on server by using async task and in the end I want to return value of uploaded file url. How can I do that
I am calling asynctask as

```
new Config.UploadFileToServer(loginUserInfoId, uploadedFileURL).execute();
```

and my asynctask function is as:

```
public static final class UploadFileToServer extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, String> {

            String loginUserInfoId = "";
            String filePath = "";
            long totalSize = 0;
            public UploadFileToServer(String userInfoId, String url){
                loginUserInfoId = userInfoId;
                filePath = url;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                // setting progress bar to zero
                super.onPreExecute();
            }

            @Override
            protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
                // Making progress bar visible

                // updating progress bar value
            }

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
                return uploadFile();
            }

            @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
            private String uploadFile() {
                String responseString = null;

                HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(Config.HOST_NAME +     "/AndroidApp/AddMessageFile/"+loginUserInfoId);

                try {
                    AndroidMultiPartEntity entity = new AndroidMultiPartEntity(
                            new AndroidMultiPartEntity.ProgressListener() {

                                @Override
                                public void transferred(long num) {
                                    publishProgress((int) ((num / (float) totalSize) * 100));
                                }
                            });

                    File sourceFile = new File(filePath);

                    // Adding file data to http body
                    entity.addPart("file", new FileBody(sourceFile));

                    totalSize = entity.getContentLength();
                    httppost.setEntity(entity);

                    // Making server call
                    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                    HttpEntity r_entity = response.getEntity();

                    int statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
                    if (statusCode == 200) {
                        // Server response
                        responseString = EntityUtils.toString(r_entity);
                    } else {
                        responseString = "Error occurred! Http Status Code: "
                                + statusCode;
                    }

                } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                    responseString = e.toString();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    responseString = e.toString();
                }
                responseString = responseString.replace("\"","");
                return responseString;

            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
                super.onPostExecute(result);
            }

        }
```

Comment: Now you getting result as a String in onPostExecute().Then whats the problem?

Comment: i want result string where i am calling asynctask @DonChakkappan

Comment: you mean that you want execute() to return a string?

Comment: yups  @lelloman.. how can i get?

Comment: I don't know, I doubt it is even possible since the asynctask run on another thread. the whole point of using asynctask is that execute() will not freeze the UI while performing long running task. you should get your string inside onPostExecute

Answer (score 0):

Try my code as given below.

```
public Result CallServer(String params)
{
try
{
    MainAynscTask task = new MainAynscTask();
    task.execute(params);
    Result aResultM = task.get();  //Add this
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
     ex.printStackTrace();
}
 return aResultM;//Need to get back the result
```

}

Comment: where will i write this ?

Comment: this is ugly, seriously

Comment: In my code, MainAyncTask is my AsyncTask. You can implement this logic where you call your AsyncTask.

Answer (score 0):

You've almost got it, you should do only one step. As I can see, you are returning the result at the `doInBackground` method (as a result of calling `uploadFile`). Now, this value is passed to the `onPostExecute` method, which is executed on the main thread. In its body you should notify components, which are waiting for result, that result is arrived. There are a lot of methods to do it, but if you don't want to used 3rd party libs, the simplest one should be to inject listener at the `AsyncTask` constructor and call it at the `onPostExecute`. For example, you can declare the following interface:

```
public interface MyListener {
    void onDataArrived(String data);
}
```

And inject an instance implementing it at the `AsyncTask` constructor:

```
public UploadFileToServer(String userInfoId, String url, MyListener listener){
    loginUserInfoId = userInfoId;
    filePath = url;
    mListener = listener;
}
```

Now, you can simply use it at the `onPostExecute`:

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    listener.onDataArrived(result);
    super.onPostExecute(result); //actually `onPostExecute` in base class does nothing, so this line can be removed safely
}
```

If you are looking for a more complex solutions, you can start from reading [this](http://blog.nikitaog.me/2014/10/11/android-looper-handler-handlerthread-i/) article.